# How to use isolation forest from sklearn to return the positions of anomalies?

Tags: scikit-learn

Assuming there is a $n$ x $m$ matrix with $n$ features and $m$ samples (each row is a feature and each column is a sample). I would like to use isolation forest in sklearn to return the positions of anomaly samples, for example, it returns an array [3,9,28,66] which contains the positions of columns of anomalies. Could anyone help me to do this by giving a small example code? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to call the `predict` method on your matrix, which returns an array of `+1/-1` for inliers/outliers, assuming your IsolationForest is already fitted. Note that the matrix should be of the form (rows=samples x columns=features).

Something like this should do it

```
mdl = IsolationForest(...)
mdl.fit(...)
#your matrix "X" should be transposed to the form (m samples x n features)
pred = mdl.predict(X.T)
anomaly_columns = np.where(pred==-1)
```